# Hide div after no mousemove, but disable if drop-down is open

Tags: jquery, settimeout, mousemove

I have a tab, which when clicked triggers a drop-down menu. When the mouse hasn't moved for a set amount of time, the tab fades out, when you move the mouse, it fades back in.

What I would like to do is if the drop-down is open, disable the fading out, until it's closed again.
I've got pretty close, but my knowledge of jQuery isn't quite there.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ue3L/).

```
var timer;
$('.container').mousemove(function (e) {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }
    $('.tab').fadeIn('fast');
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.tab').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: Seems like you know how to clear the timeout. That's all you should do when the tab opens - then set the timeout again when it closes.

Comment: I'm *kinda* doing that, but it fades out once, and then clears the time out.. Would you be able to show exactly what you mean with the fiddle? - Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ue3L/1/ I added two comments to give you an idea. You might also need to reorganize your code a bit to avoid repetition.